# When clear browser history spring security session not cleared?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, spring-security

If I cleared my browser history, the spring security's session not cleared it shows below error :

> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationException:
>   Maximum sessions of 1 for this principal exceeded.

But I need maximum session should be 1. Here is my config code

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

http.headers().frameOptions().disable().
authorizeRequests()


        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('FULL ACCESS')")
        .antMatchers("/companymaster/**").access("hasRole('FULL ACCESS')")
        .antMatchers("/AccountSetting/**").access("hasRole('FULL ACCESS')") 


        .antMatchers("/","/dashboard/**").access("hasRole('FULL ACCESS') or hasRole('LIMITTED ACCESS')")
        .and()              
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").successHandler(customAuthenticatonSuccessHandler)           
                        .usernameParameter("username")
                        .passwordParameter("password")              
                        .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").invalidateHttpSession(true)           
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                        .permitAll()

                        .and().csrf()   
                          .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")       
                          .and()
                          .sessionManagement()

                          .sessionFixation().changeSessionId()
                            .invalidSessionUrl("/login?invalid")                        
                            .maximumSessions(1)                                                         
                                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                                .expiredUrl("/login?expired")                                   
                                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());    
 }
```

Comment: Can you describe your problem more clearly?

Comment: After signed in my application am going the clear my browser history then refresh my application it will redirect to the login page but i have tried to enter same user again it throws "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationException: Maximum sessions of 1 for this principal exceeded".

Comment: Sure it is. The fact that you clears browser cookies doesnt mean that this user session has gone somewere from server. It's still there. So in this case you just gonna have to wait till this session expires. I guess the only thing you can do is to lower session timeout value as much as possible, so you dont need to wait too long.

Comment: @leffchick there is any solution for that

Comment: Presumably you can remove `maxSessionsPreventsLogin` to allow the user to log in again (invalidating the original session).

Comment: No if an user logged in  dont allow the same user again. But i need to invalidate when clear the browser history